# Classifications of life purposes

Tags: life, meaning-of-life, self-cognition

Can all life purposes be classified as a mixture of some of the following four areas?

- Hedonism
- Making an impact in your physical reality
- Fulfilling the plan/desire of some supernatural entity (or entities)
- Nihilism (no life purpose at all, just stay alive for the sake of it)

Comment: you would need to define your terms, i think

Comment: What you mean by "define your terms"?

Comment: idk, i guess you mean by hedonism "the pursuit of pleasure" but it's not clear how it differs, if it does, from your other classifications. didn't a greek say that everyone pursues their own happiness, whatever they claim? i'm just not getting it yet

Comment: i guess you mean by hedonism "the pursuit of pleasure" but it's not clear how it differs, if it does, from your other classifications.

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: are you being obnoxious, by quoting me with no comment, i can't tell? apologies either way. if you don't find the comment helpful, why not consider humanism, where does that fit?

Comment: "i guess you mean by hedonism "the pursuit of pleasure" but it's not clear how it differs, if it does, from your other classifications."     Sometimes making an impact in your physical reality is not "pleasurable"(e.g. cleaning your house, staying late at night to take care of your kids, etc). Fulfilling the plan of a supernatural entity is not necessary pleasurable(e.g. Benedictine frailes self flagellating). Nihilism is basically staying alive for no reason at all.

Comment: ok so they're overlapping categories? like i say in my last comment, your definitions aren't clear enough for me to agree or disagree, with e.g. humanism. at present they seem arbitrary constructions, but i'm not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67127/discussion-between-user3293056-and-user63152).

Comment: ["ok so they're overlapping categories?"]  Yes.    ["your definitions aren't clear enough for me to agree or disagree, with e.g. humanism."]  I believe Humanism is more related to make the world a better place . Hence I believe Humanism is more in the "Making an impact in your physical reality" category.

Answer (score 1):

No.

One counter-example disproves your theory that this is a complete list, and I don't believe that [Utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism) falls into any of your categories.

The meaning of my life can only be measured against whether or not I make other people happy.

This is not about impacting my physical reality;  It's about their mental reality. Nor is it hedonism; which is, in my definition, about my happiness.  I do believe this is meaningful, and don't believe it has anything to do with supernatural entities (ruling out #3 and #4)

Comment: You're rejecting God's authority as an objective standard, but then you turn around and assert that there exists some other standard that makes other people's happiness the measure of all meaningfulness. That has a certain Platonic ring to it. Does such a standard really exist objectively, or is it just your opinion? If it's all just your opinion, why shouldn't we simply ignore it?

Comment: @PédeLeão I'm genuinely confused; What has god got to do with the question of whether or not 'All life purposes fall into one of those 4 categories'?   All I'm saying is that 'Utilitarianism' is not defined by fulfilling some supernatural entity's purpose, therefore does not fit into category 3

Comment: This assumes a standard of measure: "The meaning of my life can only be *measured* against whether or not I make other people happy." But except for God, no objective standard is possible, so your answer doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: "except for God, no objective standard is possible " Citation needed!

Comment: I'm not trying to convince you of anything. It's *your* answer, and I'm asking *you*: Does such a standard really exist objectively, or is it just your opinion? If it's all just your opinion, why shouldn't we simply ignore it?

Comment: I don't understand what this comment has to do with my answer as it relates to the question.  How does it help OP?  Utilitarianism is one of many 'life purposes'  It does not fall into the other categories.Therefore the answer to OP's question is 'No'.  If the question was "Does utilitarianism prove that there is no god' I'd understand why you felt the need to interject..

Comment: The same could be said about utilitarianism: What objective standard makes utility the measure of a meaningful life? Does such a standard really exist, or is it just your opinion?

Comment: Why does something have to have an 'objective standard' for it to fit OP's definition of 'Life Meaning'? Nihilism and Hedonism certainly don't have objective standards. I'm not arguing that utilitarianism is a particularly good 'life meaning' only that it is one.

Comment: An objective standard is required for meaning to rise above triviality and empty opinion. Utilitarianism doesn't qualify. Nihilism and hedonism deny any such standard, and thus they don't even pretend to have any answer for a meaningful life: "If the dead don't rise, let us eat and drink for tomorrow we die!"

Comment: JeffUK.  Utilitarianism = "the doctrine that actions are right if they are useful or for the benefit of a majority". Hence, Utilitarianism falls in category #2 (people's mental reality is part of your reality[other people's brain is a physical entity in your reality]). Also, the only way that you can make someone happy is by taking actions in your physical reality.

Comment: Their brains are physical, their minds are mental,not physical. As I said. OP needs to be much more careful with their definitions

Comment: Even if i accept your dualistic view of the brain and mind(i think that a materialistic model of the universe carries less assumptions and as consequence is a more racional model of reality.), in order to impact other peoples mind, you must take sctions in your physical reality.

Answer (score 1):

Classifications are more likely to be conventional than descriptive. So they are also more or less useful.

A desirable feature of classification is exhaustivity but is easily obtained by including a class "Other". Thus a most rudimentary form is a series of descriptions ('bullets'), with the last one labelled 'other'.

Logic also achieves exhaustion if a feature, that is a predicate, applicable to the whole domain is chosen: anything is either an "A" or a "not-A". If two such *independent* features are known, on may obtain a complete fourfold classification (e.g. 11, 10, 01, 00).

The four suggested purposes are actually two pairs that are not well separated as they are based on something like ego vs. not-ego and plan vs. no-plan, both being roughly along the axis inside vs outside.

Comment: "A desirable feature of classification is exhaustivity but is easily obtained by including a class "Other".  Adding "Other" weakens the explanatory power of the model.  I think it is better to amend the model when a purpose that could be classified in the "Other"  class is found. BTW the classes are more clusters than tight classes(i.e.  A particular purpose could be a mixture of any number of classes.)

Comment: "The four suggested purposes are actually two pairs that are not well separated as they are based on something like ego vs. not-ego and plan vs. no-plan, both being roughly along the axis inside vs outside." So my understanding of your model is a 3D space with 3 axis: - Self benefit vs non Self benefit, - Deterministic? vs Nondeterministic? - natural? vs supernatural? Is my understanding of your model correct?

Comment: Your comment inspire my to express the model as a 3D space where each of the 3 categories is an axis and Nihilism is the Origin(or center of the 3D space.)